# Circe Encoding Sealed Traits and Co Product Case class Fails

Tags: json, scala, shapeless, circe

I have the following case class:

```
case class SmartMeterData(
  dateInterval: SmartMeterDataInterval = HalfHourInterval(),
  powerUnit: PowerUnit = KWH,
  smartMeterId: String,
  timestamp: String,
  value: Double
) {
  def timeIntervalInDuration: FiniteDuration = dateInterval match {
    case HalfHourInterval(_) => FiniteDuration(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    case FullHourInterval(_) => FiniteDuration(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
  }
}
object SmartMeterData {
  sealed trait SmartMeterDataInterval { def interval: String }
  case class HalfHourInterval(interval: String = "HH") extends SmartMeterDataInterval
  case class FullHourInterval(interval: String = "FH") extends SmartMeterDataInterval

  sealed trait PowerUnit
  case object WH  extends PowerUnit
  case object KWH extends PowerUnit
  case object MWH extends PowerUnit
}
```

I just wrote a very simple unit test to see if Circe works for my scenario:

```
"SmartMeterData" should "successfully parse from a valid JSON AST" in {
    val js: String = """
      {
        "dateInterval" : "HH",
        "powerUnit" : "KWH",
        "smartMeterId" : "LCID-001-X-54",
        "timestamp" : "2012-10-12 00:30:00.0000000",
        "value" : 23.0
      }
      """
    val expectedSmartMeterData = SmartMeterData(smartMeterId = "LCID-001-X-54", timestamp = "2012-10-12 00:30:00.0000000", value = 23.0)
    decode[SmartMeterData](js) match {
      case Left(err) => fail(s"Error when parsing valid JSON ${err.toString}")
      case Right(actualSmartMeterData) =>
        assert(actualSmartMeterData equals expectedSmartMeterData)
    }
  }
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
Error when parsing valid JSON DecodingFailure(CNil, List(DownField(dateInterval)))
```

Is there a known limitation with circe where it does not yet work for my case above?

Comment: You can print `expectedSmartMeterData.asJson` and see that it's `{"dateInterval":{"HalfHourInterval":{"interval":"HH"}},"powerUnit":{"KWH":{}},"smartMeterId":"LCID-001-X-54","timestamp":"2012-10-12 00:30:00.0000000","value":23.0}`.

Comment: https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason that Circe wouldn't work, but the way you've designed the data model, there's basically zero chance of any Scala JSON library that can automatically generate an encoder/decoder working without a lot of manual work.

For example

```
sealed trait SmartMeterDataInterval { def interval: String }
case class HalfHourInterval(interval: String = "HH") extends SmartMeterDataInterval
case class FullHourInterval(interval: String = "FH") extends SmartMeterDataInterval
```

the schema for both, in any Scala JSON library which automatically derives instances for `case class`es, would be along the lines of

```
{ "interval": "HH" }
```

for `HalfHourInterval` and

```
 { "interval": "FH" }
```

for `FullHourInterval` (i.e. because each has a single string field named `interval`, they're effectively the same class).  In fact your model allows you to have `FullHourInterval("HH")`, which for at least one method of generating a decoder for an ADT hierarchy in circe (the one in the documentation which uses shapeless) would be the result of decoding `{ "interval": "HH" }`, since that essentially takes the first constructor in lexical order which matches (i.e. `FullHourInterval`).  If the intent is to only allow full- or half-hour intervals, then I'd suggest expressing that as:

```
case object HalfHourInterval extends SmartMeterDataInterval { def interval: String = "HH" } 
case object FullHourInterval extends SmartMeterDataInterval { def interval: String = "FH" }
```

I'm not directly familiar with how circe encodes `case object`s, but you can pretty easily define an encoder and decoder for `SmartMeterDataInterval`:

```
object SmartMeterDataInterval {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[SmartMeterDataInterval] =
    Encoder.encodeString.contramap[SmartMeterDataInterval](_.interval)
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[SmartMeterDataInterval] =
    Decoder.decodeString.emap {
      case "HH" => Right(HalfHourInterval)
      case "FH" => Right(FullHourInterval)
      case _ => Left("not a valid SmartMeterDataInterval")
    }
 }
```

You would then do something similar to define an `Encoder`/`Decoder` for `PowerUnit`

Comment: I'm hitting this error: The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: Either[String,com.bigelectrons.models.SmartMeterData.SmartMeterDataInterval]
    Decoder.decodeString.emap( interval => {

Comment: @sparkr You should slightly fix pattern matching.

Comment: D'oh, that's what I get for live-coding in SO answers. :)